# wxPython OnExit() not stoping thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm trying to create a thread, and end it when the frame of a wxPython app is closed. Here's my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import time, wx
from threading import Thread

class UpdateThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stopped = False
        Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped:
            self.updateExchange()
            time.sleep(1)
    def updateExchange(self):
        print("Updated...")

class tradeWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Exchange", size = (500, 190))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
    def OnExit(self):
        tickThread.stopped # I've also tried: tickThread.stopped = True

tickThread = UpdateThread()
tickThread.start()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = tradeWindow(parent = None, id = -1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

But when I close the frame, it keeps printing.

Comment: `tickThread.stopped = True` is definitely *closer* to the solution (`tickThread.stopped` would never do anything). Have you tried putting a print statement in `OnExit` to make sure it's called?

Comment: @DavidRobinson it's not being called, weird...

Comment: I'd have to check, but I don't think `wx.Frame` _has_ an `OnExit`; that's `wx.App`.

Comment: Based on some Googling, I think you are missing a line in your `__init__`: `self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnExit)` (please give it a try before I post it as an answer, though)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I added that at the end of `__init__`, and when I clocked the close button, I got `TypeError: OnExit() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. I added a useless argument to OnExit(), and now it runs the OnExit() function, but doesn't close the window.

Comment: @tkbx: Good, that's progress. Did you change the line to `tickThread.stopped = True`?

Comment: You're mixing up exit (something the app does) and close (something a window does). Which one are you trying to handle here?

Comment: @DavidRobinson yes, when I click the close button, it stopps printing. The only problem is that it doesn't exit (and that I've got a useless variable)

Comment: @abarnert I'm trying to stop the thread when the window is closed so the script can complete

Comment: @tkbx: Please look at my answer. And you should read through either the tutorial I linked, or another one; you have to get the basics right before you can try to add on to them.

Comment: @abarnert There was no confusion over apps vs frames, someone elsewhere mistakenly told me to use `OnExit()`. `setDaemon` seems like a much cleaner approach, and was designed for this exactly.

Comment: @tkbx: Whoever told you to use `OnExit` with a `Frame`… I don't know what else you'd call that but confusion over apps vs. frames. Meanwhile, `setDaemon` is designed for when you don't need a guarantee that they'll ever finish anything, release resources, etc. That may or may not be your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magic `Frame.OnExit` method. You're mixing up frames and apps. Frames, like other windows, close. Apps exit.

So, you could put your code in your app class's `OnExit` method. But that's not what you want here.

Look at [this simple tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/Oninitandonexit.htm) for the `OnExit` method. Again, it's not what you want here, but you should know how it works (and which object it gets called on).

You can always bind `EVT_CLOSE` to call anything you want in your window. But you have to do this explicitly.

Normally, you'd call the method `OnClose` or `OnCloseWindow`. Calling it `OnExit` is just going to lead to major confusion (as it has).

The event handler method that you bind to has to actually be an event handler, meaning it takes an `event` parameter (as well as the `self`).

Next, if you add an `EVT_CLOSE` handler, you're overriding the default one, meaning that `Destroy` never gets called unless you do it yourself.

Here's [a tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Python/0380__wxPython/Framewitheventsoncloseonclosewindow.htm) on binding `EVT_CLOSE`, which shows all of the above steps.

Finally, as DavidRobinson explained, just doing `tickThread.stopped` won't do anything; you have to set it to `True`.

Putting it all together:

```
class tradeWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Exchange", size = (500, 190))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)
    def OnClose(self, event):
        tickThread.stopped = True
        self.Destroy()
```

---

One more note:

In any serious threaded program, if you want to share a value between threads, you generally need to synchronize it with some kind of sync object. If you're waiting for a signal from another thread, the typical way to handle that is with a [`Condition`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#condition-objects). If, on the other hand, you just want to share the value, you can use a [`Lock`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#lock-objects).

If you really know what you're doing, you can often get away with letting the Global Interpreter Lock handle synchronization for you. But in general, this is a bad idea. For example, your main thread could be running on core 0, and your background thread on core 1, and there is nothing in the Python language definition that guarantees that the computer will ever copy the updated value from core 0's cache to core 1's. So, your background thread could be spinning forever, watching the old value and never getting the new value to look at. As it turns out, with CPython 2.0-3.3 on an x86, this can't possibly happen with your code—but on less you can prove that (or at least identify the cases that are safe), don't count on it.

---

Finally, you asked whether a daemon thread is an appropriate solution. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> The significance of this flag is that the entire Python program exits when only daemon threads are left.

In other words, your program can exit without having to stop your daemon threads. But…

> Note Daemon threads are abruptly stopped at shutdown. Their resources (such as open files, database transactions, etc.) may not be released properly. If you want your threads to stop gracefully, make them non-daemonic and use a suitable signalling mechanism such as an `Event`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `tickThread.setDaemon(True)` before `tickThread.start()` - [Daemon threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) should exit with their parent threads.

Comment: Seems perfect so far, are there any drawbacks to this?

Comment: @tkbx: If you want any kind of clean shutdown, you don't get it this way. If you don't care about clean shutdown, this is an easy fix.

Comment: @abarnert what exactly do you mean by "clean shutdown"? The `OnClose` method takes care of everything manually, instead of passing the work on to Python?

Comment: @tkbx: Daemon threads are not shut down cleanly, they just stop running at some arbitrary point. If you want to make sure they've finished, or release some system resources, or flush writes to a text file or a database so they don't get lost, you can't do it this way. Read the first Note in [the docs on Thread Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects).

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't call `setDaemon`. That's "old" in 2.x and "deprecated" in 3.x. As the docs say, just set the `daemon` property directly.

Comment: Is setting `thread.stopped` to True cleaner than setting the thread as a daemon?